# How to customize height of buildings with the OSM add-on?

Tags: add-on, blender-osm

I'm having problem regarding to the height of each of the building. I want to have different heights of the building like what is look like in that particular place. What should I do? I was thinking if the way to do this is by customizing each building I have in my osm and that is way too much time needed in order to finish my city. Any suggestions and answers are much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to bse. Have a *blend_osmium* addon (utilizing the wonderfully quick  [pyosmium](https://docs.osmcode.org/pyosmium/latest/) ) well and truly on the backburner. The concept I was musing: using the props from  the OSM objects to drive the scale of the mesh, or  shape keys or bones.  Re your question, please specify with some data on how you imported OSM, and look for osm namespace tags in custom properties, or vertex group names.

Comment: The lates version of blender-osm addon does randomizing of the buldings height. You can get the addon for free at https://gumroad.com/l/blender-osm